# Can I replace the search bar with Programmable Search by Google?

Tags: search, google-search

I have the [Savia theme](https://themeforest.net/item/savia-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/7299471) which is no longer being supported by the developer.  The search bar shows up on the top right-hand corner of the page, so I was thinking of adding the script Google provides when creating a custom search bar right where it's at.

[image: Location of Search Bar on site]

I'm not entirely sure where to put this code in my theme files, nor will it work.

Has anyone done this before? If so, did it work?

Any sort of help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a `searchform.php` in your theme directory?

Comment: Yes, you should check Google CSE. Apart from this lot of plugins are available in repositry.

Comment: Start by checking `header.php`, you will find the search form or the file that contains the form.

Then replace the form with the code from Google custom search